# How to display Operating System information in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

i want my jsp page to display the operating system information to the user.

Comment: Do you want the information of the *server* or the *client* ?

Comment: i want both server and client os information.

Comment: Displaying or including the system properties is an information leakage vulnerability "CWE-615: Information Exposure Through Comments" https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/615.html and should be avoided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Server side OS information**
JSP which is java can find the OS of the computer where it is executing. we can use the getProperty() method to find the System properties of the system. It returns a String with the name of OS. It supports various OSs in java.

Example:

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example for Printing the OS name</title>
</head>

<body>
<%
 out.println("OS: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

**Client side information**

```
String agent = request.getHeader ("user-agent");
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (agent ,";");
st.nextToken ();

// Get the user's browser name
String userBrowser = st.nextToken ();

// Get the user's operating system name
String userOs = st.nextToken ();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is user agent sniffing. It's available by `request.getHeader("user-agent")`. There's even a 3rd party webservice to which you can submit this string and obtain detailed information: http://user-agent-string.info

Another way is using a Java applet and gather the information by `System.getProperty("os.name")`. This is a bit more reliable since the user agent can be spoofed by the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use script to get the PC info, such as:

```
<script>
    document.write(navigator.userAgent + "<br />");
</script>
```